# Amazon AWS: how to return top sellers by the week, month or year?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I access the amazon product advertising api with following parameters:

```
params.put("Service", "AWSECommerceService");
params.put("Operation", "BrowseNodeLookup");
params.put("AWSAccessKeyId", MY_AWS_KEY);
params.put("AssociateTag", MY_AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
params.put("BrowseNodeId", input);
params.put("ResponseGroup", "TopSellers");
```

It works nice and I get a list of 10 topsellers in the specified browse node.

My question is: is there a way (like a parameter to specify) to return the top-seller list for the previous year or previous month or previous week? Or a custom specified date range?

What does the default search return - is it all-time top-sellers? If so, how can I get more recent top sellers? (as I want my list to update (change) regularly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, so I'll answer since no-one has (in 10 days :-) )

Just use `Power` search parameter and specify it's value to `before`, `after` or `during` `[date]`.

For example: `Power=pubdate:during 2016`.